# On an SQL Select, how do i avoid getting 0 results if I want to query for optional data in another table?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with Customers which includes their contact person in the helpdesk. I have another table that lists all vacancies of the helpdesk employees - if they are currently sick or on vacation etc.

I need to get the helpdesk contact and the start/end time of their vacation IF there is an entry.

I currently have this (simplified):

```
SELECT * 
FROM dbo.Customers, dbo.Projects, dbo.Vacations
WHERE ($Phone = dbo.Customers.Phone)
  AND dbo.Customers.CustomerID = dbo.Projects.CustomerID
  AND dbo.Projects.HDContactID = dbo.Vacations.HDContactID
```

So if there is a vacation listed in the Vacations table, it works fine, but if there is no vacation at all, this will not return anything - what i want is that if there is no vacation, it simply returns the other data, and ignores the missing data (returns NULL, doesn't return anything, not important)

In any case, I need to get the `Customers` and `Project` data, even if the query can't find an entry in the `Vacations` table. How would I do this? I pretty new to SQL and couldn't find a similar question on this site

EDIT: I'm using SQL Server, currently using HeidiSQL

Comment: Use left join for the table which may not have data but should not impact the whole select query.

Comment: Aside: I hope `$Phone` doesn't indicate you are embedding parameters in the text. You should be using proper SQL parameters like `@Phone`. And you shouldn't use old style `,` joins, they were deprecated years ago

Comment: FYI, 3+ part naming for columns for to be deprecated. Get in the habit of aliasing your objects, and prefixing your columns name with that alias. It'll also make your SQL *far* more succinct. As for your joins, it's 2021! You've had 28 years to adopt the explicit JOIN syntax; why are you *still* using that old 80's syntax? [Bad Habits to Kick : Using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins)

Comment: @Charlieface its a UCCX variable, nothing SQL related, but thanks - and regarding the bad code, im just taking over old code and adding stuff, my job luckily isnt to refactor the database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below query:

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.Customers, dbo.Projects
left join dbo.Vacations on dbo.Projects.HDContactID = dbo.Vacations.HDContactID
WHERE ($Phone = dbo.Customers.Phone)
AND dbo.Customers.CustomerID = dbo.Projects.CustomerID
```

Comment: does exactly what i needed, thanks! (can accept in 8 minutes)

Answer (score 1):

Use left join as mentioned by @Flying Thunder,

Example of the left join:

> ```
> SELECT country.country_name_eng, city.city_name, customer.customer_name
> FROM customer
> LEFT JOIN city ON customer.city_id = city.id
> LEFT JOIN country ON city.country_id = country.id;
> ```

You can find a nice guide for the joins and SQL here:

https://www.sqlshack.com/learn-sql-join-multiple-tables/

Answer (score 1):

You should be using `LEFT JOIN`.  In fact, you should *never* be using commas in the `FROM` clause.  That is just archaic syntax and closes the powerful world of `JOIN`s from your queries.

I also recommend using table aliases that are abbreviations of table names.  The best are abbreviations for the table names:

```
SELECT *
FROM dbo.Customers c LEFT JOIN
     dbo.Projects p
     ON c.CustomerID = p.CustomerID LEFT JOIN
     dbo.Vacations v
     ON p.HDContactID = v.HDContactID
WHERE c.Phone = $Phone;
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you try this to skip vacation record if not present like this:

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.Customers, dbo.Projects, dbo.Vacations
WHERE ($Phone = dbo.Customers.Phone)
AND dbo.Customers.CustomerID = dbo.Projects.CustomerID
AND (dbo.Vacations.HDContactID IS NULL OR dbo.Projects.HDContactID = dbo.Vacations.HDContactID)
```